# java syntax int compareQuantity = ((Fruit) compareFruit).getQuantity(); not understood

Tags: java

I can across the following code in [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/), which I don't understand

```
public int compareTo(Fruit compareFruit) {
    //I don't understand this typecasting
    int compareQuantity = ((Fruit) compareFruit).getQuantity(); 
    //ascending order
    return this.quantity - compareQuantity;
    //descending order
    //return compareQuantity - this.quantity;
}
```

1. why are we typecasting `compareFruit` to `Fruit` type, when it is already a `Fruit` type to begin with? It seems redundant.
2. Where did the `getQuantity` method come from? Where can I see the source code for this ?

I tried to look through some documentation but could not find anything.

Comment: 1. Don't blindly copy code you find on the internet.
2. In the `Fruit` class on the same page (Section 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cast is actually redundant since the mathod compareTo already takes a Fruit as a parameters, so there's no need for it.

As for the second question, the getQuantity method came from the Fruit class itself:

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>{

    // ...
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    // ...

}
```

Comment: @user3120233 Don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) why are we typecasting compareFruit to Fruit type, when it is already a Fruit type to begin with? It seem redundant

Yes, it is redundant. There's no need to do the type casting. That line can (must) be changed to:

```
int compareQuantity = compareFruit.getQuantity();
```

> 2) Where did the getQuantity method come from? Where can I see the source code for this ?

It is defined in the `Fruit` class above:

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
    //...
        public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type cast is redundant, you are right.
`getQuantity()` comes from the implementation of the Fruit class.
See:

```
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Casting is not required in this case. The syntax is correct bu cast is redundant.
2. It is defined in the Fruit class few lines above the compareTo method.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are correct, it is redundant
2. `getQuantity` is a method that is either declared in `Fruit`, or in a class that `Fruit` extends.  it returns an int.